# How to decrypt the name of columns from view?

Tags: sql-server, view, datatypes, system-tables

I had to deal with a third-party database, I am trying to get all columns used in a view but I got them encrypted
e.g: instead of getting `int` for `NUMERO_SALARIE` I got `TNumSal` why?

```
DECLARE @TableViewName NVARCHAR(128)
SET @TableViewName=N'DP_SALARIE'
SELECT b.name AS ColumnName, c.name AS DataType, b.max_length AS Length
FROM sys.all_objects a
INNER JOIN sys.all_columns b
ON a.object_id=b.object_id
INNER JOIN sys.types c
ON b.user_type_id=c.user_type_id
WHERE a.Name=@TableViewName
AND a.type IN ('U','V')
```

[image]

Is there any way to decrypt them?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Looks like a user defined data type to me.

By looking into `sys.types` and joining the columns `system_type_id` and further defining that `system_type_id` should be equal to `user_type_id` the query should give you the unterlying system type name.

So your code should look like this

```sql
DECLARE @TableViewName NVARCHAR(128)
SET @TableViewName=N'DP_SALARIE'
SELECT b.name AS ColumnName, c.name AS DataType, b.max_length AS Length
FROM sys.all_objects a
INNER JOIN sys.all_columns b
ON a.object_id=b.object_id
INNER JOIN sys.types c
ON b.system_type_id=c.system_type_id
WHERE a.Name=@TableViewName
AND a.type IN ('U','V')
AND c.system_type_id = c.user_type_id
```

Comment: Thanks, now `NUMERO_SALARIE` is int not TNumSal